# Azure API Management JWT validation fails

Tags: azure, jwt, azure-api-management

I'm trying to implement JWT validation as demonstrated in [this video](https://azure.microsoft.com/pl-pl/resources/videos/episode-177-more-api-management-features-with-vlad-vinogradsky/).

To achieve this I've implemented the following policies:

```
<policies>
<inbound>
    <validate-jwt header-name="Authorization" failed-validation-httpcode="401" failed-validation-error-message="No auth" require-expiration-time="false" require-signed-tokens="false">
        <issuer-signing-keys>
            <key> base64key </key>
        </issuer-signing-keys>
    </validate-jwt>
    <return-response>
        <set-status code="200" reason="OK" />
        <set-body>test</set-body>
    </return-response>
    <base />
</inbound>
<backend>
    <base />
</backend>
<outbound>
    <base />
</outbound>
<on-error>
    <base />
</on-error>
```

*require-signed-tokens* and *require-expiration-time* will be enabled in production - I was trying to disable as much validation as i could just to get this running.

Then on JWT.io I'm generating a token:
[image]

Then it's time to get some data from the API:

```
import urllib.request

headers = {"Authorization": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOiIxNTM0MDAzOTk4In0.0DlazlR4-InCb-m0dBs-9BbPbyvu5s7Opr8uXIUaMdA"}
api_request = urllib.request.Request("https://someapi", headers=headers)
try:
    api_response = urllib.request.urlopen(api_request)
    print(api_response.read())
except urllib.error.HTTPError as e:
    print(e.read())
```

Note that there is no *Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key* header as the product containing the API doesn't require a subscription, thou I've also tested it with one.
And the result:

```
b'{ "statusCode": 401, "message": "No auth" }'
```

API request trace doesn't provide any useful information.

Is there anything obvious that I'm missing?

Comment: if your policies are exactly like shown above, you have a leading and a trailing blank in your key: `<key> base64key </key>`

Comment: @jps I've added them just here.

Comment: Refer to this link: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/248703-api-management/suggestions/34221133-jwt-validation, you may get some insights on the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, thanks to the [ULR](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/248703-api-management/suggestions/34221133-jwt-validation) in [Swikruti Bose](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8188714/swikruti-bose)s comment I was able to pinpoint and eliminate the problem.
Turns out that trace in Azure portal **does not** display all available information.
To be specific: it lacks the *on-error* entry.

After viewing the full trace, which location was provided in *Ocp-Apim-Trace-Location* response header, I've found this little nugget:

> The algorithm: 'HS256' requires the SecurityKey.KeySize to be greater than '128' bits.

After providing a longer key, everything worked as intended.

This is what I get for being lazy on testing.

Comment: Another way to detect this is to still send subscription key along with request (open products do not require key, but still accept one), and request tracing via ocp-apim-trace header. Then this error would've appear in request trace.

Comment: The problem is, it did not appear there. In the portal i could see traces for _inbound_, _backend_ and _outbound_ policies. This error was was visible in _on-error_ policy, which was not displayed in the portal. Another thing is that you won't even get a trace without a subscription key.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add "`bearer`" to the `Authorization` header value, i.e.:

`headers = {"Authorization": "bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOiIxNTM0MDAzOTk4In0.0DlazlR4-InCb-m0dBs-9BbPbyvu5s7Opr8uXIUaMdA"}`

Comment: I've tried this as well, but with no luck.
If you fast forward the referenced video to 21:07 you'll notice that there is no `bearer ` in the headers.

Answer (score 0):

1. I create the following policies. Please note that the key value should be Base64 string

```html
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <validate-jwt header-name="Authorization" failed-validation-httpcode="401" failed-validation-error-message="No auth" require-expiration-time="false">
            <issuer-signing-keys>
                <key>UGFzc3dvcmRraHNhZXJhdmJhZSdyZWp2dmFlcg==</key>
            </issuer-signing-keys>
        </validate-jwt>
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

2. Navigate to https://jwt.io/ and create my token. Add your key value (mine is “UGFzc3dvcmRraHNhZXJhdmJhZSdyZWp2dmFlcg==” which is encoded value for Passwordkhsaeravbae'rejvvaer) to “your-256-bit-secret” and click on the “secret base64 encoded”

[image]

My Token was :

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOiIyNDc1ODc4MzU3In0.oDLvHDYVMzVYNdwQ1gGE8-n_-tA_8I4DJ-8dWjlluR8
```

3. In the end, we could test it from the azure portal.

[image]